# handling exceptions on tasks on .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm getting an odd exception on task creation in .net 4.0.

I'm getting the exception on windows service with a Global Updomain unhandled exceptions handler so I don't have the exact stack: `A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property.`

I think it occurs on the following code section:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < _workers.Length; ++i)
        {
            int j = i;  // copy 

            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!_workers[j].Join(4000))
                        LogWriter.Trace("Failed to join thread", "ThreadFailureOnDispose");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnLogged(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            });

        }
```

Anyone got an idea? Is it something with the aggregated exception feature?

Comment: There's some pretty good information about this here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/ee5dba5d-eea9-4d85-8f58-c2e1c71ef33a

Comment: Fix your UnhandledException event handler first.  Are _workers Tasks as well?

Comment: no. _workers are threads. what do you mean fix my UnhandledException event handler ? from some reason the windows service stops, altough the execption is caught and logged in the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I think that Task should catch AggregateExecption when using Parallel.For\Foreach as follows:

```
  try
        {
            Parallel.For(0, _workers.Length, i =>
            {

                DoWork(i);

            });

        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            // Assume we know what's going on with this particular exception.
            // Rethrow anything else. AggregateException.Handle provides
            // another way to express this. See later example.
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                OnLogged(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom of

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/27/9913610.aspx

for some useful info.

I don't think this is coming from the code you have showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the exception is of type [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) (for future reference include the exception type when asking questions—it is *key information*).

This includes the exceptions thrown in its [`InnerExceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions.aspx) property.

Comment: how should i do it? any examples?

Comment: @user437631 For debugging look at the output, identify what's failing and fix it. At runtime handle cases you can handle at runtime inside the task, or a Continuation set for exceptions. I.e. as for any exception.